# Sort List of Values in a Map in descending order

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have a Map with List of Doubles.

unsorted map contents: {A=[0.02, 0.03], B=[0.0, 0.01], C=[0.01, 0.0], D=[0.05, 1.03], E=[1.01, 0.03]}

I need to sort in descending order for List(0). I have tried the below logic but its sorting in ascending order.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("A", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(0.02,0.03)));
map.put("B", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(0.00,0.01)));
map.put("C", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(0.01,0.00)));
map.put("D", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(0.05,1.03)));
map.put("E", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.01,0.03)));
        
        
Map<String, List<Double>> output = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().get(0)))
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue,(a,b) ->a, LinkedHashMap :: new));
        
        
System.out.println("After sort: " + output);
```

Actual output:
{B=[0.0, 0.01], C=[0.01, 0.0], A=[0.02, 0.03], D=[0.05, 1.03], E=[1.01, 0.03]}

Expected output:
{E=[1.01, 0.03], D=[0.05, 1.03], A=[0.02, 0.03], C=[0.01, 0.0], B=[0.0, 0.1]}

Please help me with logic on Java8 streams.

Comment: The `Comparator` that you have is `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>> compareFirstValue = Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().get(0));`, but what you need is `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>> reversedOrder = compareFirstValue.reversed();` ..... aside: `Arrays.asList(0.02,0.03)` is sufficient for your initialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> output = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().get(0))))
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue,(a,b) ->a, LinkedHashMap :: new));
```